# mongoose unable to make nested search through "field.attributes"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```
 newFormName = req.body.name;
  newFormQuestions = req.body.questions;
  formId = req.body.formId;

  User.updateOne(
    {
      "forms._id": formId,
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "forms.$.name": newFormName,
        "forms.$.questions": newFormQuestions,
      },
    },
    (errUpdate, resultUpdate) => {
      if (errUpdate) {
        return res.status(500).json({ sucess: false, error: errUpdate });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({ sucess: true, data: resultUpdate });
      }
    }
  );
```

the above code is responsible to update certain field in the user database.

> Example of how user data looks like

```
 

    [{
                "enrolledEventID": [],
                "isOrganiser": true,
                "isAdmin": false,
                "forms": [
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdsadsad"
                            },
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdasdasdasd"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5f6070b5002a5249b050bd1e",
                        "name": "Test Form 4",
                        "dateCreated": "2020-09-15T07:43:49.389Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdsadsad"
                            },
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdasdasdasd"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5f607140cd6faa39241f7c8a",
                        "name": "Test Form 56",
                        "dateCreated": "2020-09-15T07:46:08.012Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionType": "Rating",
                                "textInputQuestionTitle": "asdasdasd",
                                "totalRating": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdasdasdasd"
                            },
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdasdasdasdasd"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5f6315145e6c794e78bcce73",
                        "name": "New Form",
                        "dateCreated": "2020-09-17T07:49:40.307Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionType": "Rating",
                                "textInputQuestionTitle": "asdasdasdsadad",
                                "totalRating": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5f6316895e6c794e78bcce74",
                        "name": "New Formasdasdasd",
                        "dateCreated": "2020-09-17T07:55:53.537Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdsadsad"
                            },
                            {
                                "questionType": "Text",
                                "textInputLabelName": "asdasdasdasd"
                            }
                        ],
                        "_id": "5f632b0f12f05d5028c96942",
                        "name": "Test Form 23232323",
                        "dateCreated": "2020-09-17T09:23:27.137Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "_id": //id,
                "fullname": //name,
                "email": //hotmail,
                "password": //password,
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "enrolledEventID": [],
                "isOrganiser": true,
                "isAdmin": false,
                "forms": [],
                "_id": //id,
                "fullname": //name,
                "email": //email,
                "password": //password,
                "__v": 0
            } ]
```

and the problem is that the match will always return 0, I'm new to mongoose and it seems that I should be able to access to the `forms._id` through `"forms._id"` in the criteria after done some research, what did I do wrong ?

I have ensured that the formId is existed in the user data.

Comment: if `forms._id` is object id in data then you need to convert to object id using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(formId)`

Comment: solved it , your one is the answer

Comment: i am not answering because its just typo or you missed the type conversation from string to object. You can remove your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure newFormQuestions have the same object keys with questions.

Do console.log for every step you aren't sure of.

As an alternative for this mongoose update, use
const temp = User.find({forms._id:formId}) first,

then you could use User.save() after assigning the value into the object you've found.

Good Luck ^^